# VS professional 2017 test explorer is blank

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I updated my visual studio 2017 to latest version (15.7.3)
test explorer panel is blank.everything was fine until i updated this.

While building solution 'The code analysis package dint loaded correctly' error message displays. 
I tried following:-

1. clearing component modal cache.
2. restart system/VS.
3. Run devenv/ setup as admin.

nothing working.I am unable to select default process architecture

[image]

Comment: So what does the referenced log file say? (You can press CTRL-C while the dialog has focus to copy the text - including the log file location - to your clipboard)

Comment: Can you pls share path?

Comment: It's in the dialog - "c:\users\partha.s\…"

Comment: had a similar problem too, "Devenv.exe /ResetSettings " helped me. but it resets all settings of vs.  so if you don't find any other solution try this

Comment: Nothing seems to help.This is killing me :(

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5wDB4D, 29 ERROR LegacySitePackage failed for package [Code Analysis Package]Source: 'mscorlib' Description: Value does not fall within the expected range. | 830 ERROR SetSite failed for package [Code Analysis Package](null)  | 831 ERROR End package load [Code Analysis Package]

Answer (score 0):

Repairing VS resolved the problem